# Sending a byte array over TCP using a socket in VB.NET

Tags: arrays, vb.net, sockets, tcp

I am currently developing a small program that sends a file over TCP.
I am using Visual Studio 2010 and the programming language is VB.NET
The way i want it to send the file is by first putting the file into a byte array which i already figured out and is working now, but i need to send the byte array one byte at a time so i can see how far it is with sending bytes. Now i thought, i could just get 1 byte from the array and put it in a temporary byte array to then send it using *`tcpServer.Send(tempbyte)`*

but all i get is this error

> ```
> > `error  1   Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Send' can
> > be called with these arguments:
> >     'Public Function Send(buffers As System.Collections.Generic.IList(Of System.ArraySegment(Of Byte))) As
> > Integer': Value of type 'Byte' cannot be converted to
> > 'System.Collections.Generic.IList(Of System.ArraySegment(Of Byte))'.
> >     'Public Function Send(buffer() As Byte) As Integer': Value of type 'Byte' cannot be converted to '1-dimensional array of
> > Byte'.  C:\Users\Sander\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\File
> > transfer\Form1.vb   40  13  File transfer`
> ```

How can i fix this since i am stuck :(

Thanks in advance :)

The code that i have problems with: (for some reason i had to split the code)

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        Dim filename As String
        Dim i As Integer
        CurrentOperationLabel.Text = "Current operation: Reading file into memory..."
        ProgressBar1.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee
        filename = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
        Application.DoEvents()
        Dim bytes() As Byte = IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filename)
        FileByteLength = bytes.Length
        Label3.Text = "Transfered bytes: 0 / " & FileByteLength.ToString 



    CurrentOperationLabel.Text = "Current operation: Transfering file..."
    ProgressBar1.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Blocks

    Dim tempstring As String = ""
    Dim tempbyte As Byte
    FileByteCounter = FileByteCounter + 1
    For i = 0 To bytes.GetUpperBound(0)
        Application.DoEvents()
        tempbyte = bytes(i)
        tcpServer.Send(tempbyte) 'this is the point it fails at :/
        FileByteCounter = FileByteCounter + 1
        Label3.Text = "Transfered bytes: " & FileByteCounter.ToString & " / " & FileByteLength.ToString
        ProgressBar1.Value = FileByteCounter / FileByteLength * 100
    Next i

    i = 0
    FileByteCounter = 0
    FileByteLength = 0
End Sub`
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151893/discussion-on-question-by-sander-b-sending-a-byte-array-over-tcp-using-a-socket).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problems have been resolved, but the solution was no longer relevant to the question since Visual Vincent helped me by making me start from scratch since the way i wanted it to work was super inefficient if it would even work at all. He suggested a lot of things that i should do and at the end it all worked beter than if we would have continued with the code i already had. So thanks Visual Vincent for helping me out!